# document.URL does not work in chrome or firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I am using `document.URL` function to load a web page through javascript. It works fine in IE however chrome and firefox gives problems. Nothing is reloaded. Is there an alternate way?
The command I am passing is

```
document.URL = 'samplepage.php';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
location.href="samplepage.php"
```

Comment: +1 @Sanks: According to the standard, `document.URL` is read only ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-46183437)), which makes sense -- you can't change where the *document* is, only what the window is looking at. @Shakti Singh has pointed you at the usual way of doing this, which is via `window.location`, which is only now [being standardized](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location) but which is very broadly supported.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome to be compliant, you need to ensure that the protocol is specified, otherwise the href will be relative to the current path.

```
url = 'google.com'
window.location.href = 'http://'+url;
```